# google cloud function in multiple files without firebase

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I had once created firebase cloud functions in  multiple files and deployed and it was pretty straight forward.

Now I am creating google cloud function with node.js without firebase, and facing issues with organizing multiple files and deploying multiple functions.

I looked over google many links, it looks either I am missing some basic concept or not getting proper link,
as of now whatever I found demosntrating only single function written in index.js file and deploying with mentioning the function name

Any help
appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy functions with gcloud, you can only deploy one function per invocation of the CLI.  It doesn't work at all like the Firebase CLI where you can collect a bunch of function into a single file for simultaneous deployment.  If you want to deploy multiple functions with gcloud, you are just going to have to run a command for each function.  If you like deploying them all together, I suggest creating some sort of shell or batch script to run them all together.